# Select Single Node with a attribute name in vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, selectsinglenode

Have an xml file

```
<DataSource>
     <localdata>
        <add context="Localization">
           <parameter name="timeout" type="int" defaultvalue="60"/>
           <parameter name="address" type="string" defaultvalue="192.168.9.45" />
           <parameter name="port" type="int" defaultvalue="6789"/>
        </add>
       <add context="General">
           <parameter name="timeout" type="int" defaultvalue="60"/>
           <parameter name="address" type="string" defaultvalue="192.168.9.478" />
           <parameter name="port" type="int" defaultvalue="5674"/>
        </add>
    </localdata>
   </DataSource>
```

I need to  get the element whose attribute is `context="General"` using vbscript

I can get the top node with this statement

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.load("DataConfiguration.xml")
Set queryNode = xmlDocument.selectSingleNode(".//localdata")
```

But not sure how to extend this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get any node, you can use this

```
Set queryNode = xmlDocument.selectSingleNode(".//node()[@context = 'General']")
```

or, specifically for the `add` node

```
Set queryNode = xmlDocument.selectSingleNode(".//add[@context = 'General']")
```

This is using XPath, which may require you to set the selection namespace property of the DomDocument

```
xmlDocument.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

You might want to search for a XPath tutorial, such as [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) - New Link