# VBScript Object Compose

Tags: json, object, com, vbscript

So i'm using a vbscript code through my Com Objects in order to decode a json file
at first my VBs code was:

```
Function filejson(json) 
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim objStream, strData 
  Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
  objStream.CharSet = "utf-8" 
  objStream.Open 
  objStream.LoadFromFile(json) 
  strData = objStream.ReadText()
  filejson=strData
End Function 

Function str2json(json,value) 
  On Error Resume Next
  Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl") 
  scriptControl.Language = "JScript" 
  Set searchResultObject = scriptControl.Eval("(" + json + ")")
  str2json=Eval("searchResultObject" & value )
End Function

Function result(json,value)
   On Error Resume Next
   result=str2json(filejson(json),value)
End Function
```

So i was just taking every value i wanted just with

```
result("movie.json",".adult") for example:
```

With Json:

```
{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/hbn46fQaRmlpBuUrEiFqv0GDL6Y.jpg"}
```

And i was taking just fine the "false"

But then , my jsons got more tricky...

```
{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/hbn46fQaRmlpBuUrEiFqv0GDL6Y.jpg","belongs_to_collection":{"id":86311,"name":"The Avengers Collection","poster_path":"/qJawKUQcIBha507UahUlX0keOT7.jpg","backdrop_path":"/zuW6fOiusv4X9nnW3paHGfXcSll.jpg"}}
```

But still i was able to get data from there with my second argument: ".belongs_to_collection.id" Until THIS:

```
{
    "adult": false,
    "backdrop_path": "/hbn46fQaRmlpBuUrEiFqv0GDL6Y.jpg",
    "belongs_to_collection": {
        "id": 86311,
        "name": "The Avengers Collection",
        "poster_path": "/qJawKUQcIBha507UahUlX0keOT7.jpg",
        "backdrop_path": "/zuW6fOiusv4X9nnW3paHGfXcSll.jpg"
    },
    "alternative_titles": {
        "titles": [
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "IT",
                "title": "I vendicatori"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "BR",
                "title": "Os Vingadores"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "GB",
                "title": "Avengers Assemble"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "US",
                "title": "Marvel's The Avengers"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "SE",
                "title": "Avengers 3D"
            },
            {    
               "iso_3166_1": "ES",
                "title": "Marvel Los Vengadores"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "PL",
                "title": "Avengers 3D"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "IL",
                "title": "הנוקמים"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "US",
                "title": "The Avengers 3D"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "CZ",
                "title": "Avengers"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "TW",
                "title": "復仇者聯盟"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "DE",
                "title": "Marvel's The Avengers - Die Rächer"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "DE",
                "title": "The Avengers - Die Rächer"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "VE",
                "title": "Los Vengadores"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And i tried to get one of the alternative titles, i tried with my default method...
result("movie.json",".alternative_titles.titles.0.title") but null was what i got...

So i used it for
result("movie.json",".alternative_titles.titles") to check the result
and the result was:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

After some time trying to figure out what to do since i couldn't access the sub object with a simple number (.1 , .0 ...) i tried to create a function to do things a bit more easier, though failed:

```
Function filejson(json) 
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim objStream, strData 
  Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
  objStream.CharSet = "utf-8" 
  objStream.Open 
  objStream.LoadFromFile(json) 
  strData = objStream.ReadText()
  filejson=strData
End Function 

Function str2json(json,value) 
  On Error Resume Next
  Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl") 
  scriptControl.Language = "JScript" 
  Set searchResultObject = scriptControl.Eval("(" + json + ")")
  parameters=Split(value,".")
  fullparm="obj"
  obj=Eval("searchResultObject" & fullparm )
  For Each parm in parameters
      MsgBox("Parameter: "&parm&" | Old Object: "& obj)
      If Eval("obj."&parm) = "[object Object]" Then
          If IsNumeric(parm) Then
              i=0
              For Each new_obj in obj
                  If Trim(i) = Trim(parm) then
                      MsgBox("New Object: " & "obj | Value: " & new_obj)
                      obj=new_obj
                      fullparm="obj."
                  End If
                  i=i+1
               Next
          Else
              obj=Eval("obj." & parm)
              fullparm=fullparm&"."&parm
              MsgBox("New Object: " & "obj." & parm & " | Value: " & obj)
          End If
      Else
          str2json=obj
          Exit Function
      End If
  Next
  MsgBox(fullparm)
  str2json="false"
End Function
Function result(json,value)
    On Error Resume Next
    result=str2json(filejson(json),value)
End Function
```

Any ideas how to manage to Get the value i want by just having the same input?

"alternative_titles.titles.0.title" (get 1 sub object.title).
Also it could have more than one sub dimension...jsons....

And i HAVE to use VBScript and NOT JScript. It used within combojects.
with JScript its not able to open a file with UTF8. IN VBScript it is with ADODB.Stream

Comment: I really think that you might be able to adapt the class found here: http://www.aspjson.com/;  just have to take the server object off and I think it should be good.

Comment: You can use COM objects in JScript using [`ActiveXObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Provided you're not in a security sandbox (i.e., a web browser), you should be able to use an ADODB.Stream in JScript the same as you would in VBScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometime ago, I wrote a JSON to XMLDOM converter (see [Decode/Encode JSON with VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153925/decode-encode-json-with-vbscript)
). When applied to your JSON, it produces the following XMLDOM:

```
<OBJECT adult="false" backdrop_path="/hbn46fQaRmlpBuUrEiFqv0GDL6Y.jpg">
    <OBJECT id="86311" name="The Avengers Collection" poster_path="/qJawKUQcIBha507UahUlX0keOT7.jpg" backdrop_path="/zuW6fOiusv4X9nnW3paHGfXcSll.jpg"/>
    <OBJECT>
        <ARRAY>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="IT" title="I vendicatori"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="BR" title="Os Vingadores"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="GB" title="Avengers Assemble"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="US" title="Marvel's The Avengers"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="SE" title="Avengers 3D"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="ES" title="Marvel Los Vengadores"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="PL" title="Avengers 3D"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="IL" title="הנוקמים"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="US" title="The Avengers 3D"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="CZ" title="Avengers"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="TW" title="復仇者聯盟"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="DE" title="Marvel's The Avengers - Die Rächer"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="DE" title="The Avengers - Die Rächer"/>
            <OBJECT iso_3166_1="VE" title="Los Vengadores"/>
        </ARRAY>
    </OBJECT>
</OBJECT>
```

As an XMLDOM it should be a simple matter of using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) queries and selectSingleNode to get the values you want. For example: [Select Single Node with a attribute name in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370640/select-single-node-with-a-attribute-name-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this issue, but I found the way to access the list array objects using the script control. When addressing the member you can use square brackets around the index number e.g. obj.[index#]. Hope this helps!

Not sure if it's relevant either, but to get a variable index of an object in this case I found I have to use the eval() function. Here's an example of what I'm doing for my JSON array where count is the number of objects in the array:

```
Do While index < count
  types(index) = eval(".Data.Array.[" & cstr(index) &"].Type")
  index = index + 1
Loop
```